# "Photos of Jonathan" missing while 'viewing as public'

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos, facebook-privacy

When I look at my Facebook photos via "View as Public" I notice I don't have the *Photos of Jonathan* tab. I only have the *Jonathan's Photos* and the *Albums* tab. I browsed some profiles and noticed some have it and some don't—I'm guessing this is a privacy settings thing.

How do I set the privacy so that I'll have the *Photos of Jonathan* tab?